# Como hacer Pixel Perfect en Unity 5x?

Tags: unity, unity2d

Mi problema es que en Unity 5x (en mi caso 5.6.7) no hay un componente Pixel Perfect Camera (ya que si no me equivoco este se implementa en Unity 2019), como hago pixel perfect en esta versión de Unity?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.